# How do I get a toggle button to toggle an array back and forth from descending to ascending?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I am using bubbleSort, and I can get the array to toggle from its original order to descending, but I am having trouble getting it to go from descending back to ascending. Should I just copy the bubbleSort code and flip the greater than/less than signs? Any help is appreciated!

```
var myStuff = [];
function myfunctionA() {
  var enteredvalue = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
  // alert(typeof Number(document.getElementById('numbers').value));
  if (enteredvalue == "") {
    alert("Input is not a number");
  } else if (isNaN(enteredvalue)) {
    alert('You need to enter a valid number!');
  }
  var elementExists = false;
  var x = document.getElementById('numbers').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < myStuff.length; i++) {
    if (myStuff[i] == Number(x)) {
      elementExists = true;
    }
  }
  if(elementExists != true) {
    myStuff.push(Number(enteredvalue));
    alert('Thank You for entering a valid number.');
  } else {
    alert('Element is here');
  }
}
function myfunctionB() {
  window.alert(myStuff.length);
}
function myfunctionC() {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < myStuff.length; i++) {
    sum+=myStuff[i];
  }
  alert(sum);
}
function myfunctionD() {
  if (myStuff.length == 0) {
    alert("already empty");
  } else {
    myStuff = [];
  }
  alert("Array Empty");
}
function myfunctionE() {
  alert(myStuff.join('\n'));
  {
    if (myStuff == []) {
      alert("Enter something into Array")
    }
  }
}

function bubbleSort() {
  var sorted = true;
  var temp;
  while(sorted) {
    sorted = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < myStuff.length-1; i++) {
      if(myStuff[i] < myStuff[i+1]) {
        temp = myStuff[i];
        myStuff[i] = myStuff[i+1];
        myStuff[i+1] = temp;
        sorted = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you not just use `[ ... ].sort()`?

Comment: `[...].sort()` and then `[...].reverse()` as suggested by @LiYinKong

Comment: I was told not to use .sort or .reverse for this assignment. @sarbbottam

Comment: However, if I were to use .reverse, where would I input that code into my existing code?

Comment: Does this mean you are trying to implement `asc` & `desc` sort functionalities?

Comment: basically I am trying to insert numbers into an array. They are (so I am told) naturally going to be displayed ascending when you call for the function to show the array. When I hit the toggle button it goes to descending, but when I hit toggle again it just stays at descending. I need it to be able to switch back and forth. Hopefully this makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need a toggle to tell which way you are going.

```
var isAscending = false;
```

Then in your bubbleSort function inside the for-statement, above the if-statement.

```
var sortComparison;
if (isAscending) sortComparison = myStuff[i] > myStuff[i];
if (!isAscending) sortComparison = myStuff[i] < myStuff[i];
```

Then replace your if-statement with:

```
if (sortComparison)
```

Finally, once you have finished sorting, you can toggle your variable:

```
isAscending = !isAscending;
```

Though, I'd recommend using a toggled variable and simply using sort() and reverse() instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/ytcax0qc/

Comment: so instead of using:                                                                                     var sorted = true;
     var temp;
     while(sorted) {
     sorted = false;         I should replace that with:                                    var isAscending = false;       ?

Comment: No, the isAscending var sits outside the function.  If you leave sorted or isAscending inside the function then as soon as the function call ends that variable gets reset.

Comment: so should it look something like this?      
    function bubbleSort() {
    var sorted = true;
    var temp;
    while(sorted) {
        sorted = false;
    var sortComparison;
    if (isAscending) sortComparison = myStuff[i] > myStuff[i];
    if (!isAscending) sortComparison = myStuff[i] < myStuff[i];
        for(var i = 0; i < myStuff.length-1; i++) {
            if (sortComparison) {
                temp = myStuff[i];
                myStuff[i] = myStuff[i+1];
                myStuff[i+1] = temp;
                sorted = true; isAscending = !isAscending;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ytcax0qc/ - Make sure to open your dev console as I'm dumping the output to console.log in that Fiddle.

Comment: Appreciate your help, David. What does the console.log function do in this instance? Is it just making sure the function runs properly? Thank you

Comment: console.log is simply a debug tool used by Firebug and Chrome (as well as Node.js) that outputs the contents of whatever you pass it to the developer console.  If you are using Chrome (press F12 and click on the Console tab) if Firefox and Firebug, simply open Firebug and look in the Console.  I'm unsure if IE supports it or not.

Comment: Ah okay. So if you didn't use console.log, what would you use? Or should I always use console.log if using chrome?

Comment: console.log is simply a debug tool.  When you are working on code you often want to simply output something for debugging purposes.  That is what it is for.  It should not be used in Production, not without taking further steps to ensure it won't cause issues in IE.